# Create a like button with Stimulus Reflex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, stimulus-reflex

#### business class

```
class Business < ApplicationRecord
    .........
    belongs_to :user 
    has_many :likes
```

#### like class

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user  
  belongs_to :business
  .....
```

#### user class

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :likes
  has_many :businesses
  ....
```

#### business/show.html.erb

```
<%= button_tag "Like", data: {reflex: "click->Likes#like", id: @business.id} %>


class LikesReflex < ApplicationReflex  
 def like    
 business = Business.find(element.dataset[:id])    
 business.likes.find_or_create_by(user: current_user)  
 ......
```

i need help to set the likeReflex controller .
i want login user to like business and add them to thier user.likes

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would implement a like button in StimulusReflex.

In the view template:

```
<%= button_tag "Like", data: {reflex: "click->Posts#like, id: @post.id} %>
```

In your reflex class:

```
class PostsReflex < ApplicationReflex
  def like
    post = Post.find(element.dataset[:id])
    post.likes.find_or_create_by(user: current_user)
  end
end
```

A common **pattern**, which is more secure is to **use signed global ids**, then you can have create something that works more like a concern:

```
<%= button_tag "Like", data: {reflex: "click->Likes#create", sgid: @post.to_sgid_param }
```

Then you have a Reflex class like:

```
class LikesReflex < ApplicationReflex
  def create
    likeable = GlobalID::Locator.locate_signed(element.dataset[:sgid])
    likeable.likes.find_or_create_by(user: current_user)
  end
end
```

Comment: i have edited the question with your code. maybe that helps. i quess i need to chnage the reflex action. Thanks